# Is zakat mandatory at the age of 17?

Tags: fiqh, zakat

Is it mandatory for me to pay Zakat, even though I don't have my own job and I always save my money as cash? Also, not to mention that I'm saving up for a PS4 or a custom PC, which are quite expensive to buy.

Comment: I suppose that even if we assume that you might to have to pay zakat, the amount you need to pay for is higher then this and if the money isn't saved for one whole lunar year there's no need to pay Zakat. For example Imam al-Laith ibn Sa'ad was very wealthy but never needed to pay Zakat, as he never saved some money for 1 year!

Comment: @medi-saif Is my mom wrong by saying that since I don't have a job, is it still obligatory for me to pay Zakat? She told me that when you start working, then you pay Zakat. Is she wrong?

Comment: @medi-saif My parents give me money, BTW.

Comment: Yes she would be wrong, as zakat is fard/farz for every baligh (adult) muslim, but as i said according your Questions (text) i assume you won't reach the nisab, but feel free to check out if you reached the nisab https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisab. And Stuff like PC etc. wouldn't count as a value for zakat only a car if we could apply the zakat for horses on it, but this is a Question for a scholar, not me! As we don't pay zakat for what i would like to call "functional objects".

Comment: @medi-saif What is the minimum limit to reach the nisab?

Comment: It depends on the actual gold price see the wikipedia link

Answer (score 3):

All Praise to Allah Swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

**Zakat is obligatory on every free adult and sane Muslim when he or she possesses   the nisab and a lunar year has passed over it. Zakat is due on Gold Silver Cash Trade-goods,freely-grazing livestock kept for milk or breeding like camels, cows, sheep and goats.**

Now as per your query ,if you are saving this amount for a long time like a year has passed over it and you have reached your age of puberty then you have to  figure out the month the day and the amount when it reached the nisab level,, you can calculate from zakat calculator too, and if after calculation you figure out that your zakatable valauables reaches the value of the nisab and year has passed over it then you are liable to pay the zakah whether you work or not and if you dont possess for an year then you dont need to .Your Query is useful as there are so many misconceptions among people that if head of the family is paying zakah then its enough for all.

Man , woman or adult children each are due to pay zakah if above conditions are  applicaple over them.Scholars have mentioned in their fatawas that it is permissible if someone from family pays the zakah on behalf of nisab holder like a woman has enough gold but she doesnt earn then her husband or other could give on behalf of her otherwise she has to give zakat from her Gold.

> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Whoever is made
>   wealthy by Allah and does not pay the Zakat of his wealth, then on the
>   Day of Resurrection his wealth will be made like a baldheaded
>   poisonous male snake with two black spots over the eyes. The snake
>   will encircle his neck and bite his cheeks and say, 'I am your wealth,
>   I am your treasure.' " Then the Prophet (ﷺ) recited the holy
>   verses:--And let not those who [greedily] withhold what Allah has
>   given them of His bounty ever think that it is better for them.
>   Rather, it is worse for them. Their necks will be encircled by what
>   they withheld on the Day of Resurrection. And to Allah belongs the
>   heritage of the heavens and the earth. And Allah , with what you do,
>   is [fully] Acquainted.. (3.180)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: I don't have a job, and the money I have is not much either, (possibly doesn't exceed $60), and I have to collect over $400.

Comment: *the pocket money. Although, I have $1000 laptop and a $200 phone, and maybe some clothes. Still, I'm living with my parents. Am I still obliged to do it? Is my mom wrong by saying that since I don't have a job, is it still obligatory for me to pay Zakat? She told me that when you start working, then you pay Zakat. Is she wrong? My parents give me money, BTW.

Comment: you dont have to give zakah on that amount ,,I have stated that there are lots of misconceptions among people so dont assume that your parents are wrong rather you can convince them to ask a mufti so misconceptions could get clear and for more you can visit this http://alsunnahfoundation.org/Academy/ZakahHanafi.pdf

Comment: Look at the phrase "free, sane Muslim" in the PDF you have sent me, I'm not free yet. I still live with my parents.

Comment: @HüdaverdiAlperenDemirok free here means that not a slave.

Comment: Look, I don't have a job, nor wealth. Zakat is only obligatory to ones who have a job and/or wealth.

Comment: You dont have worth amount as nisab (http://www.e-nisab.com) so you dont have to give zakat ,you dont have that much wealth you dont need to but if someone who is  Mature and sane keeps that much amount of cash, gold or silver and one year has passed over it then he has to give zakah irrespective of job.

Comment: @HüdaverdiAlperenDemirok "the pocket money. Although, I have $1000 laptop and a $200 phone, and maybe some clothes. Still, I'm living with my parents. Am I still obliged to do it?" No, there are no zakat on phones or laptops if they are for personal use.